# Is there any significance in N355 FWU?

Tags: doctor-who

This was always a question for me, and I never found out anything about it.

Is there any significance to N355 FWU? This appears in Season 2 Episode 6 *The Age of Steel* (it's the number plate of the van that Mickey and Jake drove away).

Please let me know if there is some significance to it or not so we can end this mystery.

Comment: Why do you think a random number plate has some significance?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because of the way they framed the shot. Either the plate number is significant, or that was just bad directing. Unfortunately, it seems like the latter is the case.

Comment: @user137369: Or the wheels were being framed, which is a conventional way to show a fast moving vehicle in a time-sensitive situation. I don't think it's fair to call this "bad directing" or "unfortunate".

Comment: The wheels weren’t being framed, the plate was. It was also not “a fast moving vehicle in a time-sensitive situation”, but the absolute opposite: a slow moving vehicle “[driving into the sunset](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RidingIntoTheSunset)” because the adventure was done. All bad directing is unfortunate. If you call attention to something unimportant to the point people thing it is important, either it is a [Red Herring](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedHerring), or bad directing. Here the latter is the case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an [entry in the Internet Movie Cars Database](http://www.imcdb.org/vehicle_171448-LDV-400-1995.html). 
In real life, N355 FWU is the license plate of [a Ldv 400 Series D 3.1t (Panel Van)](https://www.mycarcheck.com/check/options/N355FWU/) which was [registered in Leeds in 1995](http://regarchive.com/plate/N355FWU). This is consistent with the vehicle depicted in the series (screenshot below courtesy of IMCDb). So license plate is the real one of the van used for filming. In all likelihood, the van was not chosen for its license plate. The number holds no significance.

[image: N355 FWU]

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I can recall and rewatch it was never mentioned before or again.  It was just an odd framing shot on the car that lent unnecessary significance to the number plates.

Comment: yeah.. they love to focus on number plates. In the episode idiot's lantern of the second season, they focus on the number plate of the scooter. LOL whatever..

Answer (score -1):

I was just rewatching it and wondered this myself. As the show is filmed in Wales, I checked Google Translate and Nessfwu is Welsh for Next Door. I assume it's a reference to it being a parallel universe.

Comment: Is there a good reason to think that's anything more than a coincidence though? A [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17978/122024) has already indicated that 'N355 FWU' was the real life license plate number of the van used in the show, rather than a number made up for the show.

Comment: @LogicDictates - I always assumed that registration plates for vehicles in TV shows were made up to prevent unwanted attention being given to vehicles in real life, post-broadcast, but that seems not to be the case; the [Metropolitan Police guidelines](https://www.met.police.uk/SysSiteAssets/media/downloads/central/advice/filming/guidelines-filming-move-london.pdf)  indicate that the rules for normal driving (e.g. car registered, taxed and insured, correct plates visible at all times) apply during filming and if you don't want to go to the trouble of obtaining "ghost plates" (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) from the DVLA for the duration of filming, you should just use the real plates. It looks like the simplest explanation (in this case) really is the best one; they just used a van with that registration number. I honestly didn't expect that and genuinely thought all TV plates were made up, so I was leaning towards the "interpretation" theory. Truly, one lives and learns. PS: the guidelines above are the Met Police's, rather than any Welsh force's, but I couldn't find anything to suggest the relevant legislation was different in Wales.

Comment: I don't think "nessfwu" is Welsh at all. Welsh for "next door" would be "drws nesaf" ("door (the) next", because Welsh syntax is different from modern English) ; neither "ness" nor "fwu" translate to anything in Welsh according to three different translation services. Plus if the car was registered in Leeds, it seems unlikely to me that an English car would have a license plate in Welsh for "next door" of all phrases.